# Dummy Results When Inserting Multiple Rows

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently created a table called Movie_Stars. It contains 6 columns: Movie_Number number unique, Movie_Title varchar2 (30) unique, Year_Released date not null, First_Name varchar2 (15), Last_Name varchar2 (15), and Movie_Category varchar2 (15). I need to insert the following values into the table:

```
insert all
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (1, 'New York Stories', 'January 1 1984', Nick, Nolte, Drama)
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)      
          values (2, 'Speed', '1999, FEB 12', Keanu, Reeves, Action)
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (3, 'Superman', '1982, MAR 7', Chris, Reeve, Action)
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (4, 'Ice Age', '2002, April 2', Chris, Rock, Cartoon)
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (5, 'Bowfinger', '2001, August 03', Eddie, Murphy, Comedy);
select * from dual;
```

However, when I ran the code, it returned the following results:

```
DUMMY
-----
1 x
```

What does that mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: `Select * from dual`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have a wrong semicolon between the `INSERT ALL` and the `SELECT`; this means that they are two different statements, not a single statement.
2. You are missing many quotes to wrap your string values
3. You can not insert date values this way; you have to use a `to_date` or use the ANSI standard

You can rewrite your code as:

```
insert all
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (1, 'New York Stories', date '1984-01-01', 'Nick', 'Nolte', 'Drama')
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)      
          values (2, 'Speed', date '1992-02-12', 'Keanu', 'Reeves', 'Action')
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (3, 'Superman', date '1982-03-07', 'Chris', 'Reeve', 'Action')
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (4, 'Ice Age', to_date ('02/04/2002', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), 'Chris', 'Rock', 'Cartoon')
into movie_stars (movie_number, movie_title, year_released, first_name, last_name, movie_category)
          values (5, 'Bowfinger', date '2001-08-03', 'Eddie', 'Murphy', 'Comedy')
select * from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you Aleksej! I thought I only needed the quotes around dates and multiple words. Another thing though, when I retrieve the data later to double, check, the date format for the 4th row didn't change even though you used the to_date function.

Comment: They are only two different methods to write a date value, but the result is absolutely the same; if you need a specific format, say because you have to get a date from an input string, you can use to_date with the appropriate format mask; if you simply need to write a date value, you can use the easier (IMHO) ANSI way